# SimpleDateFormat returning the wrong date in Java

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'm having an issue with SimpleDateFormat in Java. My code is returning the wrong date.  Help please.

```
String date_str = "Tue Mar 08 09:44:55 EST 2022";
  
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM D HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(date_str);

// Output: Sat Jan 08 14:44:55 GMT 2022
```

Comment: People this use `Date`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d`, not `D` for the day of the month. `D` is the day in the year, so 8 is the 8 of January.

```
String date_str = "Tue Mar 08 09:44:55 EST 2022";
  
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(date_str);
                                       // ^---Here

// Output: Tue Mar 08 15:44:55 CET 2022
```

Check the full list of patterns [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).